# Upload multipart file as JSON encoded

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to upload a multipart file as JSON encoded, rather than URL encoded. It seems to default to URL encoded, but I can't figure out a way to change this. With other Alamofire methods you can explicitly state the encoding like:

```
Alamofire.request(_, _, parameters: _, encoding: .JSON)
```

Is there a similar way I can change the encoding on the Alamofire upload function?